# Search JSON array for specific word

Tags: javascript, json

trying to locate the word 'London' from a  generated JSON array entered from a user.

response 200 (API example):

```
{
"latitude": 52.24593734741211,
"longitude": -0.891636312007904,
"addresses":
["10 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire",
"12 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire",
```

i wrote a function:

```
 request.onload = function() {

var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

if(request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
  var city = data.addresses;
  var london = 'London';
   var check = city.includes(london);
    if(check) {
      console.log(city);
    } else {
      console.log('not in london');
       var show = document.getElementById('incorrect_postcode').style.visibility='visible';
```

I'm unsure if I misunderstand the API or if somethings wrong here... the statement is always false.

Also tried for loop to search the length of the array to locate 'London', to no avail

Thanks.

Comment: Response is not JSON

Comment: I think both snippets are cut off

Comment: Where is London in your JSON sample?

Comment: You can do it using recursion but your question is vague

Answer (score 2):

The `addresses` array is a list of strings, each string being an address. So, none of the strings will exactly equal `'London'`, because there is more to an address than the city.

You could loop through the array of addresses and check if each string contains `'London'`, but that would also match any addresses where London is in the street name.

The better way would be to loop through the array of addresses and parse each address string to pull out the city value. Then compare the city value to `'London'`.

Note: I am assuming the second-to-last value is the city.

```js
const data = {
  "latitude": 52.24593734741211,
  "longitude": -0.891636312007904,
  "addresses": [
    "10 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire",
    "12 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire",
    "221B Baker Street, , , , , London, "
  ]
};



let desiredCity = 'London';
// array index of city after splitting the addresses
const CITY_POSITION = 5;

console.log('Addresses in ' + desiredCity + ':');

for(let i = 0; i < data.addresses.length; i++) {
  // split the address on the delimiter, ', '
  let addr = data.addresses[i].split(', ');
  
  if(addr[CITY_POSITION] === desiredCity) {
    console.log(data.addresses[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well spotted - I added this idea to my suggestion too

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

If we assume the JSON request is working, then no need to include that part.

The reason your example does not work, is that includes is looking for the complete string

Instead loop over the array and look at each string

NOTE: If you use search or indexOf, you may find London in Londonderry

```js
var response = `{
"latitude": 52.24593734741211,
"longitude": -0.891636312007904,
"addresses":
[
"10 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire, NN1 1ED",
"Bishop Street,     , , , , Londonderry, BT48 6PQ",
"12 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire, NN1 1ED",
"10 Downing Street, , , , , LONDON, SW1A 2AA"
]
}`

var data = JSON.parse(response);

var addrs = data.addresses;
console.log(addrs)
var city = 'London'.toLowerCase();
var check = addrs.filter(function(addr) {
  var thisCity = addr.split(",")[5].toLowerCase().trim()
  console.log(city,thisCity)
  return  thisCity === city
})
if (check.length > 0) {
  console.log("Yes, in "+city,check);
} else {
  console.log('not in london');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want true/false check, you can go, like:

```js
var input = {
  "latitude": 52.24593734741211,
  "longitude": -0.891636312007904,
  "addresses":[
    "10 Watkin Terrace, Northampton, Northamptonshire",
    "12 Watkin Terrace, Northampton, Northamptonshire",
    //"Baker Street, London, England",
    "Londonderry, Ireland"
  ]
};

const isLondon = obj => obj.addresses.some(addr => addr.match(/, London,/));

console.log(isLondon(input));
```

Comment: This will match on `"Londonderry, Ireland",`

Comment: @mplungjan: Now, it won't

Comment: But still  return all *cester," if you search for cester

Comment: @mplungjan: if you search for Cester, you say `addr.match(/, Cester,/)`, wouldn't it help?

Comment: Sure. Have a look at my answer for a safer test

Comment: It will fail if there is a `, name,` anywhere else in the string

Comment: @mplungjan: like, if there were country called 'London' or that API returns address somewhere in Peru, which reads simply 'London'? OP didn't provide strict source data format, if he did, I would make up regex that does exactly what's needed, believe me. Without that we can imagine all sorts of weird addresses, making mine (or yours) script fail.

Comment: My script is using position. If that works, it works better than a regex on the complete string

Comment: And mine is one line long :) As being said, it can be adjusted to take position into account, however, how can you be sure that this position is constant and address string, for example, will not have commas itself? We can play that game all day long...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple search

```js
var data ={
"latitude": 52.24593734741211,
"longitude": -0.891636312007904,
"addresses":
["10 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire",
"12 Watkin Terrace, , , , , Northampton, Northamptonshire",
 "london", 
 "londonderry, Ireland",
 "London Road"
]}

var searchFor = "london";
console.log(data.addresses.filter((item) => {
 return item.toLowerCase().split(" ").indexOf(searchFor.toLowerCase()) != -1
}))
```

Comment: This will match  "londonderry, Ireland", too

Comment: I have updated my answer, it should work as you liked

Comment: You mean `return item.toLowerCase().split(" ").indexOf(searchFor.toLowerCase()) != -1` and that will match "London Road" too

Comment: yah it will match. becouse it split London and road and if one of them containes london. then it should return London Road

Comment: I updated my answer and added london road and sorry this should be `return item.toLowerCase().split(" ").indexOf(searchFor.toLowerCase()) != -1`